# Finding the mean value of a dense matrix

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrix, mean

I'm trying to calculate the arithmetic mean of each column in a dense matrix in C#, but I'm wondering if it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Meta code

```
mean(int[,] data, int j)    
   int sum = 0;    
   for i=0 to data.Length - 1
      sum += data [i, j]
   end     
   return sum / data.Length;
```

C# code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[,]
        {
            { 1.1, 2.2 }, 
            { 3.3, 4.4 }, 
            { 5.5, 6.6 }, 
            { 7.7, 8.8 }
        };

        double meanValue = Mean(data, 0);
    }

    public static double Mean(double[,] data, int columnIndex)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        int rowsCount = data.GetLength(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount - 1; i++)
        {
            sum += data[i, columnIndex];
        }

        return sum / rowsCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you may want to make `sum` a double/decimal, depending on the desired result.

Comment: That's good but I would like to start the method like this:          public static double[] CalculateArithmeticMean(DenseMatrix matrix) {}

Comment: @MichaelLoftus So then make that method, have a `for` loop in which you go through each column and call the method defined here.  Add all of the results to an array and return it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Should I create a for loop that wraps around the other for loop with something like for (int a = 0; matrix.ColumnCount; i++)

Comment: @MichaelLoftus I have added C# code. You may need to adjust it for your data type, but the algorithm stays the same.

Comment: great, is there any way to make the jagged array function like a dense matrix though?

Comment: @MichaelLoftus can you give me a sample of a dense matrix object? How does it look like? Maybe throw in some code or a link to the library you are using